# Convert binary arbitray-precision floating point to any base

Tags: floating-point, arbitrary-precision, radix

Suppose I have a binary floating point notation (e.g. 1001.011101) with arbitrary precision 2^(-n) after the floating point, how can I convert it to any base, say ternary or decimal.

For the integer part, there is a [double dabble algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) with which one can convert a binary integer number to any base system. But is there a similar method (just using shift and add, without converting it to decimal as a medium. because if you want to convert it to decimal first, sufficient large precision N will cause overflow) for binary floating points?

Answer (score 1):

Given an *n* bit binary numeral in which *m* bits are after the radix/integer point, convert the numeral to BCD using the double dabble algorithm. Include an additional max(0, 4*m*−*n* bits) after (to the right of) the original bits in the double dabble algorithm. Initialize them to zero. So, after the double-dabble algorithm completes, there will be at least 4*m* zero bits after the BCD result, providing room for fractional digits to be produced.

Then divide by 2<sup>*m*</sup> by doing the following *m* times:

- For each BCD digit that is odd, subtract six from the five bits starting at the low bit of that digit and proceeding into the next lower digit. For example, xxx1 0000 becomes xxx0 1010, and xxx1 1001 becomes xxx10011.
- Shift the entire work space one bit right.

This essentially reverses the double dabble algorithm: Everywhere the next higher digit is odd, the 16 that its low bit represents in binary relative to the next lower digit is adjusted to be 10 relative to the next lower digit, so that, when the bit shift is performed, it has the desired decimal effect.

If 4*m*−*n* is non-negative, the result is right-adjusted in the bits, representing a numeral with *m* BCD digits after a decimal point. If 4*m*−*n* is negative, the result starts *n*−4*m* bits from the right.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct. Also, why would there be 4m zero bits after shifting m times?

Comment: @SirBogman: The double dabble algorithm shifts *n* times, not *m*, as it converts the *n* bits of the numeral (the entire numeral, integer and fraction bits). Each left shift introduces a new zero bit on the right. Since we start with at least 4 *m* − *n* zero bits on the right and introduce *n* more, there are at least 4 *m* zero bits on the right after the double dabble algorithm completes. As for your lack of confidence, no basis is stated, so no response is at hand.